# functions declaration in data class Kotiln

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin, I wanted to write a function, but I see the new way of writing it with "`val`" property using `get()`. What's the difference between the below two.

```
 1)   fun sample(): String {
             return "text"
           }

   2)  val sample: String
            get() = "text"
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the kotlin documentation?

Comment: There is no difference besides how you want users to access it.

Comment: And also in intent: a property should represent an attribute or characteristic of the object it belongs to.  This means, among other things, that a getter method should generally be consistent (returning the same result unless a setter is called), not take long to run, and not have any visible side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there are is no major difference between the two snippets. I can only point you at some minor differences:

- Snippet #1 will be recognised as a declared function whereas Snippet #2 will be a declared property. This might make a difference should reflection-based logic be applied.
- Snippet #2 could never accept an argument and could never return a response of type different than the declared `val`. This is due to the nature of the `get()` abstraction. Snippet #1 could easily be extended to accept an input argument.
- Snippet #2 might have IDE complaining about a backing field being generated for the property that has no impact on the property's `get()`.
- Generally speaking, Snippet #2 could and probably should be reduced to `val sample: String = "text"`. `get()` declaration is redundant.